# run pm2 restart command which deletes .env file

Tags: node.js, pm2

When I run pm2 restart server from inside my droplet, it deletes .env file from server folder. Can't understand why? Can you help me on this?

Comment: Can you share your `ecosystem.config.js` file for pm2?

Comment: Didn't use ecosystem.config.js just used pm2 start npm --name “<app_name>” -- run start and a .env file